# Any other way to upload a file without the form

Tags: html

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

Instead of the above code,can i just use a variable like fileToUpload=pathtofile

Comment: That's a pretty significant security problem if you could, don't you think?

Comment: Using only HTML - no.

Comment: Why do you think its a security problem

Comment: What if I just put, say `fileToUpload=~/.ssh/id_rsa` on some otherwise innocuous site. Then I'd have most *nix user's private keys w/o them ever telling me it's ok.

Comment: Can javascript help with that

Comment: No, for the same reasons as above.

Comment: what about python?

Comment: why, can i ask, is the the given code too much hassle?